# Using a save class to save a value and print the previously saved value when called

Tags: java, generics

I'm studying for a final and I'm stumped on how to approach this problem.

> Write a generic class named Saver. It should have one method named
>       save. This method should store the value that is passed and return the previous value 
>       For example, this class should support the following behavior:

```
Saver<Integer> saver1 = new Saver(13);
System.out.println(saver2.save(42)); // prints 13
System.out.println(saver2.save(-999)); // prints 42
System.out.println(saver2.save(2013)); // prints -999 

Saver<String> saver2 = new Saver("foo");
System.out.println(saver2.save("bar")); // prints foo
System.out.println(saver2.save("why")); // prints bar
System.out.println(saver2.save("yar")); // prints why
```

I don't need code, I just want to know how I could accomplish this task?

Comment: I'd use Java.  Did you have a specific question?  You must have covered this in class.

Comment: It was not covered in class, it's a sample final he posted. I do need to use Java, but I have been thinking about how I could approach the problem and have tried a couple things but I just run into a wall every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saver has a field that you assign to and return its old value.

```
class Saver<T> {
    T value;

    Saver(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    T save(T value) {
        T old = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        return old;
    }
}
```

Comment: Come on, he literally asked for no code. Explain it and let him look, it would be a 10 times better learning experience. At the very least provide an extensive explanation and perhaps give the code afterwards. For such a basic question you could at least explain your thought process, that's where the actual value is.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The OP said they "didn't need code" but I don't see how else to explain it without providing code. I'm not sure what is confusing to them except that maybe they are thinking it is more complicated than it is. The text for the problem already explains it pretty clearly.

Comment: Thank you, but what is "T" in your code? How is it used and what is it for?

Comment: @DLR: if you are studying generics but you don't know what `T` is, then I fear you have skipped a chapter.

Comment: That is a generic type parameter. The `<T>` indicates that this class takes a type (another class) as an argument. Basically if you say `new Saver<Integer>` everywhere there is a `T` gets replaced with `Integer`. See the generics tutorial for more I guess: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: @JeroenVannevel the chapter on generics?

Comment: @Taylor: yes, that one.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
public static class Saver<T> {
  public Saver(T value) {
    super();
    save(value);
  }

  T value = null; // A T value.

  public T save(T value) {
    try {
      return this.value; // return the current value.
    } finally {
      this.value = value; // rely on finally to change the stored value.
    }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Saver<Integer> saver1 = new Saver<Integer>(13);
  System.out.println(saver1.save(42)); // prints 13
  System.out.println(saver1.save(-999)); // prints 42
  System.out.println(saver1.save(2013)); // prints -999

  Saver<String> saver2 = new Saver<String>("foo");
  System.out.println(saver2.save("bar")); // prints foo
  System.out.println(saver2.save("why")); // prints bar
  System.out.println(saver2.save("yar")); // prints why
}
```

And when runs it prints as follows on my machine -

```
13
42
-999
foo
bar
why
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a generic class, then you must to store the previous value in a instance variables, I post a code for you

```
public class Saver<T> {

private T value;

public Saver(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public T save(T newValue) {
    T oldValue = this.value;
    this.value = newValue;
    return oldValue;         
}
```

}